# Adding(removing) data from XML to list

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I want to add data dynamically from my xml class to list.
my xml class is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>


            <persons>
                <person id="1" >
                    <firstName>Anthony</firstName>
                    <lastName>Robbins</lastName>
                </person>
                <person id="2" >
                    <firstName>Deil</firstName>
                    <lastName>Carnegie</lastName>
                </person>
                <person id="3" >
                    <firstName>Bill</firstName>
                    <lastName>Cosby</lastName>  
                </person>
                <person id="4" >
                    <firstName>Albert</firstName>
                    <lastName>Einestein</lastName>  
                </person>
                <person id="5" >
                    <firstName>George Bernard</firstName>
                    <lastName>Shaw</lastName>
                </person>
            </persons>
```

i want to add(remove) (first name + last name) of selected id to(from) my list with every click on the button.
in other words i want to add for example (first name + last name) of id=4
and then with other button(like remove button) i want to remove that from my list.

i used data provider but the problem is it adds whole xml class instead of my selected element of class.
whats the solution?

Comment: As I understand you need a list with custom item renderer. You have to create an ArrayCollection from the xml you have, array collection item example: {id:4, fn:Albert, ln:Einestein}, then you can bind array to your list, remove/add items from this collection, and at the end create new xml from changed data.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not very clear to me. Following is the solution what i made up from your question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            private var lastId:int = 5;
            private function addNode():void
            {
                var suffix:int = int(Math.random()*100000);
                lastId++;


                var node:String = '<person id="'+lastId+'" >' +

                    '<firstName>FirstName'+suffix+'</firstName>' +
                    '<lastName>LastName'+suffix+'</lastName>' +
                    '</person>'
                var xmllist:XMLList = new XMLList(node);    
                xmlData.appendChild(xmllist);
                trace(xmlData.toXMLString())
                txtResult.text = xmlData.toString();
            }

            private function removeNode():void
            {
                try{
                    delete xmlData.person[XMLList(xmlData.person.(@id==txtId.text)).childIndex()];
                    txtResult.text = xmlData.toString();
                }catch(err:Error){
                    Alert.show("person with this id is not found.");
                }

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:XML id="xmlData" source="data.xml" />
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Form>
            <mx:FormItem label="Enter Node ID:" >
                <mx:TextInput id="txtId" restrict="0-9" />

            </mx:FormItem>
            <mx:FormItem direction="horizontal">
                <mx:Button label="Add Node" click="addNode()"/>
                <mx:Button label="Remove Node" click="removeNode()"/>
            </mx:FormItem>
        </mx:Form>
        <mx:TextArea id="txtResult" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Here in code `data.xml` is the xml in question.

Comment: Thanks you. but i mean i want to add (first name + last name) to list component (with scrollbar) not form.

Comment: i mean i want to add (first name + last name) to list component (<s:List/>) not text Area. "add" button, add each name to list and "remove" button, remove name from end of my list. in other words my problem is how do i add selected data (not whole, for example only "Anthony Robbins" and "Deil Carnegie") to my "LIST". and how do i remove my selected data (for example "Anthony Robbins") from my list.